# load duration of web page differs

Tags: performance, time, load, duration

for testing purposes I measure the time it takes for parsing, db accessing, posting and rendering of one of my web php web pages in the browser (by using Firebug's network tool). When I press F5 after clearing the cache by "Delete recent data" it takes about 5 seconds, when I hit Ctrl-F5 it takes about 20 seconds.

Isn't that the same? What's the difference between them? What is the recommended way to test the performance of php code and db access?

Thank you very much in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of reasons all of which have to do with the implementation of firebug.
You cannot test the performance on the client side since clients differ a lot and also have the network latency which is even harder rule out.
You should do this all on the server side: start a timer when the request reaches your web server and then stop it when it exits. If that is a bit difficult then in the PHP script itself you can run a wrapper script that has a start timer, a `require` statement for the script you want and a stop timer.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do know about the influence of network and browser. For many test cases this can be ignored, as we want to track only the performance difference between to states of code. So I do not want to know about the improvement of the test, actually. I'm really eager to know, what makes the Firefox perform so differently... So the main question remains unanswered.

Comment: In the least you should first verify that your server side performance is the same in both scenarios.
Then you can run Wireshark (or any packet sniffer) on the client side to see what the client actually does. I would guess it has to do with opening more TCP connections in the slow scenario while in the fast scenario it reuses more connections.